# Factorizing typescript code within Firebase cloud functions

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

Below is some working typescript code from Firebase cloud functions:

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as cors from "cors";
import {Response} from "express";

const corsHandler = cors();

admin.initializeApp();

.....

exports.hasFlagOne = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");

  corsHandler(req, resp, async () => {
    const idToken = String(req.body.token);
    admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
        .then(function(decodedToken) {
          const uid = decodedToken.uid;
          const refStr = "/Users/"+uid;
          const ref = admin.database().ref(refStr);

          if (ref === undefined) {
            resp.send({"flagOne": false});
            return;
          }

          ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            const snv = snapshot.val();

            if ((snv === undefined) || (snv == null)) {
              resp.send({"flagOne": false});
              return;
            }

            // At this point we have:
            // (snv !== undefined) && (snv != null)

            if (snv.flagOne !== undefined) {
              resp.send({"flagOne": snv.flagOne});
              return;
            }

            resp.send({"flagOne": false});
          });
          resp.send({"flagOne": false});
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle error:
          resp.send({"flagOne": "ERROR(AR)"});
        });
  }); // End corsHandler.
});
```

Now I also want to export another function:

```
exports.hasFlagTwo = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {...});
```

very similar to the one above:

```
exports.hasFlagOne = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {...});
```

The only difference between the two functions is going to be that *flagTwo* will replace *flagOne*.

In order to avoid duplicating similar code, I have done the following but it is not quite working.
Having some help by a  typescript expert would be very much appreciated.

Here is what I tried:

```
exports.hasFlagOne = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  corsManager(req, resp, "flagOne");
});


exports.hasFlagTwo = functions.https.onRequest(function(req, resp) {
  corsManager(req, resp, "flagTwo");
});


function corsManager(req:Request, resp:Response, propKey:string) {
    resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");

    corsHandler(req, resp, async () => {
      const idToken = String(req.body.token);
      admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
          .then(function(decodedToken) {
            const uid = decodedToken.uid;
            const refStr = "/Users/"+uid;
            const ref = admin.database().ref(refStr);
        
            if (ref === undefined) {
              resp.send({propKey: false});
              return;
            }
        
            ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
              const snv = snapshot.val();
            
              if ((snv === undefined) || (snv == null)) {
                resp.send({propKey: false});
                return;
              }
          
              // At this point we have:
              // (snv !== undefined) && (snv != null)
          
              handleSnapShot(resp, snv, propKey)
          
              // If handleSnapShot could not do the job:
              resp.send({propKey: false});
            });
        
            resp.send({propKey: false});
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle error:
            resp.send({propKey: "ERROR(AR)"});
          });
    }); // End corsHandler.
  } /* End of corsManager */
  
  
  function handleSnapShot(resp:Response, snpShtVal:Request, propKey:string) {
    // We have: (snpShtVal !== undefined) && (snpShtVal != null)
    if ((propKey == "flagOne") && (snpShtVal.flagOne !== undefined)) {
      resp.send({propKey: snpShtVal.flagOne});
      return;
    }

    if ((propKey == "flagTwo") && (snpShtVal.flagTwo !== undefined)) {
      resp.send({propKey: snpShtVal.flagTwo});
      return;
    }
  } /* End of handleSnapShot */
```

I hit a few problems, but the first one is this:

....  warning  'propKey' is defined but never used         @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

It is easy to see in the code that *propKey* is used.
Am I not using the proper syntax?

I also have doubts about the types I am using for the arguments of the functions:
*corsManager*  and *handleSnapShot*.

Comment: You are sending firebase realtime database `DataSnapshot` to Firebase function Request type. To fix it change the request type of snpShtVal to [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) as follows
`function handleSnapShot(resp:Response, snpShtVal:DataSnapshot, propKey:string)`. Also try changing the things as per the [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/b2N6tK6kp8tu7jliB4wL).

Comment: I am trying your suggestions; I get this message:  error TS2304: Cannot find name 'DataSnapshot'. I may need to add some import or so.

Comment: Yes you need to import `import { DataSnapshot } from "firebase-admin/database";` to make it work. Added the change to the [snippet](https://codefile.io/f/b2N6tK6kp8tu7jliB4wL).

Comment: @Sandeep_Vokkareni. I am trying to follow your suggestions to make things work, but I still face some problems. The first one being that Request does not seem to be the type I should use for the first argument of the corsManager function. I have also tried CorsRequest, but that doesn't work either.